# Amazon S3 tools for Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I need to (programmatically, in a shell script) upload an [EAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_%28file_format%29) file to an Amazon S3 bucket on Debian (5.0.4). What, if any, Debian package provides simple, scriptable tools for that?

Ideally this would be a set of command line tools akin to those in Ubuntu's [`ec2-api-tools`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fi/lucid/ec2-api-tools) package.

(I want raw S3 bucket access, so please don't suggest solutions like Jungle Disk.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

George Reese recommended `s3cmd` in ["Cloud Application Architectures"](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596156374). It seems to be readily available as a [debian package](http://packages.debian.org/sid/s3cmd).

Comment: Yeah, this is what I needed (wonder why I missed it in the first place). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Python [Boto](http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) library would be one method. Alternatively, you could use something like [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/), which allows you to mount an S3 bucket. With that solution, all you'd need to do is copy or move your EAR file to the specified mount point.

Comment: Thanks - not what I was looking for right now, but Boto seems pretty cool and I think I'll use it later when playing with Python

Answer (score 0):

[mc](http://minio.io/#mc) provides minimal tools to work with Amazon S3 compatible cloud storage and filesystems. It has features like resumable uploads, progress bar, parallel copy. mc is written in golang and released under Apache license v2.

Hope this helps.