# Amazon EC2 tools for Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

What is the recommended way of getting command-line Amazon EC2 tools on Debian? So, basically the same as [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/131864/amazon-s3-tools-for-debian), but for EC2 instead of S3.

Ubuntu has [ec2-ami-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ec2-ami-tools) and [ec2-api-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ec2-api-tools), but I couldn't find equivalent packages for Debian. A blog post titled "[Install EC2 AMI & API tools in Debian](http://geekery.etherknet.com/?p=277)" talks about installing Amazon's packages outside package management, but that seems a little clumsy.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/326684/how-to-install-a-single-package-from-debian-sid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, seems that you can use the Ubuntu .deb packages on Debian without problems! At least for the Debian stable (5.0.4) system that I'm working on, [`ec2-api-tools` from Ubuntu Jaunty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/ec2-api-tools) apparently works fine...

What I did:

1. Download the [.deb package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fi/jaunty/amd64/ec2-api-tools/download) (for amd64 in my case) of [ec2-api-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/ec2-api-tools)
2. `sudo dpkg -i ec2-api-tools_1.3.34128-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

Edit: As pointed out in comments, you might want the [package from latest Ubuntu version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/all/ec2-api-tools/download) instead. (I can't say anything about compatibility with specific Debian versions though.)

As for `ec2-ami-tools`, I got that also installed quite smoothly, but only after fulfilling some missing dependencies: `sudo apt-get install ruby libopenssl-ruby curl`. (I had to `dpkg -r ec2-ami-tools` before that worked.)

Now, the obvious question of course is: **why no official Debian packages?** It turns out that Amazon's EC2 tools are not available for Debian because of some [DFSG compliance reasons](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=515971#12). :-(

Comment: 2. sudo dkpg should be sudo dpkg (swap p and k) :)

Comment: The URL for downloading the package should probably be updated to: http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/ec2-api-tools or use the search for the latest packages: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ec2&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: Its actually more like you can use the Debian packages on Ubuntu. :)

Comment: I know Ubuntu uses Debian's packaging system. What I meant here is that *these* specific packages from Ubuntu happen to work smoothly (no dependency problems etc) on Debian too; this isn't generally true for any packages.

Comment: Just a note that the most recent packages in lucid-backports currently work fine on Debian Lenny.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 'free' implementation
   [euca2ools](http://packages.debian.org/stable/euca2ools) in Debian stable

Tools [list for the package](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/all/euca2ools/filelist)

Adding 'use limitation' clause 3.3 to EC2 tools (like Amazon did) was I think a misguided measure

Answer (score 1):

A little script to download ubuntu packages:

(getdeb-ub.sh) Assuming you have ubuntu sources list file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.list, and you had `sudo apt-get update` previously, so the list had been cached.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo mv .ubuntu.list.bak ubuntu.list
aptitude download "$@"
sudo mv ubuntu.list .ubuntu.list.bak
```

Then, run `./getdeb-ub.sh ec2-ami-tools ec2-api-tools` to download the ec2 tools from the ubuntu repositories. And later, run `sudo aptitude install ec2-api-tools-x.x.x.deb` etc., to install the deb packages with all required dependencies. (`sudo dpkg -i ...` won't install dependencies for you)

Answer (score 0):

The packages from apt-get are out of date.

There is no way (I can find) to bundle, upload, and register an AMI in the us-west-1 region.

I wasted about 10 hours trying to get them to work.  Do not recommend :(

Comment: Have you tried using Ubuntu packages as described in http://serverfault.com/questions/131970/amazon-ec2-tools-for-debian/131971#131971?